# Expected response code 354 but got an empty response in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-mail

I have been faced with this problem for the last 2 days. I have tried a lot of things to solve it with a lot of resources. Going from the same error over and over again.

##### `.env` settings:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.zamzamtradingbd.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@zamzamtradingbd.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=hellopassword123321
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@zamzamtradingbd.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

##### `config/mail.php` settings:

```php
return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [

        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],

    ],


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: I would suggest contacting your mail provider to see why you're getting this response.

Comment: MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@zamzamtradingbd.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=hellopassword123321.

This credential is working on another laravel project, but not working on my project.